# Unable to select a column on sqlite3 database

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to select a particular column of a table in a sqlite database. I am using the following:

`cursor = connection.execute('select Case from SUMMARY')`

Even though the column name is correct, whenever I run the code, i receive the following error.

The same happens when I try to fetch the column index.

Whenever i try any other column, I can fetch all the column's data.

```
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_15288/2883478922.py in <module>
      1 import sqlite3
      2 connection = sqlite3.connect("../DB_Cases.sqlite")
----> 3 cursor = connection.execute('select Case from SUMMARY') 

OperationalError: near "from": syntax error
```

Comment: `case` is a reserved word in most SQL dialects, itry double-quoting it: "Case"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`case` is [reserved keyword](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) in SQLite.

Using double quotes in the query as mentioned in the SQLite documentation should get your query working.